# Get COUNT/SUM of records based on another column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get the count/sum of the rows (COUNT () or SUM ()) based on another column (of the Type: weekly or yearly)? I have two tables:

1. Stores:

| Id | Name | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Store 1 | Weekly |
| 2 | Store 2 | Yearly |
| 3 | Store 3 | Weekly |
| 4 | Store 4 | Weekly |

2. Orders:

| Id | StoreId | OrderDate | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-31 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-12-31 | 5* |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-01-28 | 30* |
| 4 | 2 | 2022-06-30 | 50* |
| 5 | 2 | 2022-12-31 | 70* |
| 6 | 3 | 2022-06-15 | 8 |
| 7 | 3 | 2022-12-27 | 9* |
| 8 | 3 | 2022-12-31 | 3* |

a) If I pass the date range (*by weekly*,*2022-12-26* ~ *2023-01-01*), the expected result should look like this:

| Id | Name | Count of orders | Total Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Store 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | Store 2 | 3 | 150 (sum by the year when the store's type equals "Yearly": 30+50+70) |
| 3 | Store 3 | 2 | 12 (sum by the selected week: 9+3) |
| 4 | Store 4 | 0 | 0 |

If the `Store type` is **`Yearly`** then all orders will be summed up based on `StoreId` *&* `year` of `OrderDate`, if **`Weekly`** then based on StoreId & selected OrderDate.

b) I tried using `CASE` in SELECT statement, but no luck, here are part of my codes:

```
SELECT s.Id,
       s.Name,
       COUNT(o.Id) AS 'Count of orders',
       sum(o.Qty) AS 'Total Qty'
  FROM Stores AS s
  LEFT JOIN Orders AS o
    ON o.StoreId = s.id
   AND (OrderDate >= '2022-12-26' AND OrderDate <= '2023-01-01')
 GROUP BY s.Id, OrderDate
 ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT s.Id,
       s.Name,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN s.Type = 'Yearly' THEN
                o.Id
               ELSE
                CASE
                  WHEN OrderDate >= '2022-12-26' AND OrderDate <= '2023-01-01' THEN
                   o.Id
                END
             END) As 'Count of orders',
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN s.Type = 'Yearly' THEN
              o.Qty
             ELSE
              CASE
                WHEN OrderDate >= '2022-12-26' AND OrderDate <= '2023-01-01' THEN
                 o.Qty
                ELSE
                 0
              END
           END) AS 'Total Qty'
  FROM Stores AS s
  LEFT JOIN Orders AS o
    ON o.StoreId = s.id
 GROUP BY s.Id, s.Name
 ORDER BY MAX(OrderDate) DESC
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ltMkuUOg).

Comment: This one seems working!!! Lets me try! ;)

Comment: In my case, I'm using a derived table to save the trouble of getting the Count of orders. Otherwise, the same complex query to get the qty will be used again for the `count` function.

Comment: Yes! This is the final method I use to get the expected result! 
Sorry for the late reply, as many last minute projects have skipped the queue, now I can only return to this topic again. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way.
Please take note that, **`type`** is a keyword in MySQL.

```
SELECT s.id,
       s.name,
       s.type,
       COUNT(s.name) AS total_count,
       SUM(o.qty) AS total_qty
  FROM stores s
  LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON s.id = o.storeid
 WHERE (o.orderdate >= '2022-12-26' AND o.orderDate <= '2023-01-01' 
   AND  s.type = 'Weekly')
    OR  s.type = 'Yearly'
 GROUP BY s.id, s.name, s.type
```

Comment: If using this way, Store 4 is not displayed, because of 0 record in Orders table.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, calculate `count(Orders.Id)` and `sum(Orders.Qty)`

1. Stores.Type = 'Weekly': Orders.OrderDate between @start_date and @end_date
2. Stores.Type = 'Yearly': Orders.OrderDate in the year of @start_date (...all orders will be summed up based on StoreId & year of OrderDate.)

Thus, the first step is to have `where` clause to filter out Orders and then aggregate to `Store.Id` level. Then, 2nd step is to left join from `Stores` table to the result of first step so that stores without sales in specified date ranges are reported.

```sql
set @start_date = '2022-12-26', @end_date = '2023-01-01';

with cte_store_sales as (
select s.Id,
       count(o.Id) as order_count,
       sum(o.Qty)  as total_qty
  from stores s
  left 
  join orders o
    on s.Id = o.StoreId
 where (s.type = 'Weekly' and o.OrderDate between @start_date and @end_date)
    or (s.type = 'Yearly' and o.OrderDate between makedate(year(@start_date),1)
                                              and date_sub(date_add(makedate(year(@start_date),1), interval 1 year), interval 1 day))
 group by s.Id)
select s.Id,
       s.Name,
       coalesce(ss.order_count, 0) as "Count of Orders",
       coalesce(ss.total_qty, 0)   as "Total Qty"
  from stores s
  left
  join cte_store_sales ss
    on s.Id = ss.Id
 order by s.Id;
```

Output:

```
Id|Name   |Count of Orders|Total Qty|
--+-------+---------------+---------+
 1|Store 1|              1|        5|
 2|Store 2|              3|      150| <-- Store sales in year 2022
 3|Store 3|              2|       12|
 4|Store 4|              0|        0| <-- Report stores without sales
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to avoid using subqueries or CTE for this time, I only use CTE for complex queries. But I think this time it can be solved in a simpler way, somehow I just got stuck. ^^!!! But i definitely will try this out if no luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we shall extract the raw data matching the orderdate table condition, which can be used for the sake of aggregation later. Note,here I treat the date range as **inclusive**. Therefore, it shall be year 2022 and 2023 for 2022-12-26 ~ 2023-01-01 if the type is yearly.

```
    select s.id id, name,
        (case when type='weekly' and orderdate between '2022-12-26' and '2023-01-01' then qty
         when type='yearly' and year(orderdate) between year('2022-12-26') and year('2023-01-01') then qty
        end) as qt
    from Stores s
    left join Orders o
    on s.id=o.storeid;
-- result set:
# id, name, qt
1, Store 1, 5
2, Store 2, 30
2, Store 2, 50
2, Store 2, 70
3, Store 3, 
3, Store 3, 9
3, Store 3, 3
4, Store 4,
```

The rest is to do the summarisation job using the derived table. Note: Since the column `name` is not in the `group by` list, but it's actually unique for a specific storeid, we can use the any_value function to bypass the restriction which might be enforced due to the `SQL_MODE` system variable.

```
select id,any_value(name) as'Name',count(qt) as 'Count of orders', ifnull(sum(qt),0) as 'Total Qty'
from
    (select s.id id, name,
        (case when type='weekly' and orderdate between '2022-12-26' and '2023-01-01' then qty
         when type='yearly' and year(orderdate) between year('2022-12-26') and year('2023-01-01') then qty
        end) as qt
    from Stores s
    left join Orders o
    on s.id=o.storeid) tb
group by id
order by id
;
-- result set:
# id, Name, Count of orders, Total Qty
1, Store 1, 1, 5
2, Store 2, 3, 150
3, Store 3, 2, 12
4, Store 4, 0, 0
```